# Does Maven 3 provide better performance than Maven 2?

Tags: performance, maven-2, maven-3

I have tried simple:

```
 mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true
```

switching from Maven2 (2.2.1) to Maven3 (3.0.4 - 3.0.3).
But time used for build by Maven2 was lesss! For project that build by Maven2 near 16 minutes, on Mave3 - near 20 minutes.
But, also on stackoverflow I found than Maven3 has better performance. Should I create another local repository for Maven3 (I used old created by Maven2) or use additional options?
Thanks.

Comment: I can assume that some part of the time was spent on downloading artifacts. Can you execute this command 2 times both on 2nd version and 3rd and share your results? On all of our projects 3rd version performs a little bit better.

Comment: I have made build many times to exclude downloading of artifacts.

Comment: little bit better - it seems nothing.

Comment: Which areas are the most time consuming parts ? Unit Test ? Compiler ? Have you checked that? Have you fixed all plugin versions correctly to get a real accurate results in comparing them?

Comment: if you will read question - you will see: -Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven 3 should be faster than Maven 2. Of course, there's always the possibility of a performance regression for some edge cases. I'm not sure where the problem is in your case but I'd start by seeing which phase takes longer and comparing that to the Maven 2 build, for instance:

- is this a multi-module or a single-module build?
- does the build contain non-standard build extensions, for instance the `maven-bundle-plugin`?
- does the build use the latest versions of the plugins? The `maven-compiler-plugin` brings nice performance improvements for multi-module projects in version 2.4.0
- does the build reference artifacts with version ranges? I recall there were some troubles in terms of performance with early Maven 3.0.x versions
- are all plugin versions fixed in your POM? It is possible that Maven 3 brings in new plugin versions which have performance regressions

Once you narrow down the root cause you can either fix it yourself - if possible - or submit a bug report to the maven plugin or maven core.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the -T option of Maven 3 which offers the possibility to execute parts of the lifecycle in parallel.

excerpt from the --help output:

```
-T,--threads <arg>                     Thread count, for instance 2.0C
                                        where C is core multiplied
```

But it depends on which plugins versions you are using if they already up-to-date and correctly marked with @threadsafe. But sometimes it's worth a try.

Comment: I have 1 core. I have tried with -T - nothing better and not all plugins are thread-safe.

Comment: @khmarbaise: why? Even on a single core using multiple threads can help: if one thread is blocked, waiting for I/O, then another could do calculation. That would improve performance even on a single core. Granted, the question is if such constellations happen often enough in a Maven Build to be worth the hassle.

Comment: @JoachimSauer In theory you are correct,but in practise i have my doubts getting measurable improvements.